# Chicken Egg Problem - Probability

Tags: probability

I stumbled over this probability problem, the solution is explained in the textbook and i am able to follow it, until the point below where i don’t see how they arrive at the next line. I just have no clue.

[image]

The closest I get is this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV, Petra! If you click "edit" to the lower left of your question, and add the `[self-study]` tag this question will likely get more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remaining step to get what you need is that $$e^{-\lambda}=e^{-\lambda p}\cdot e^{-\lambda q}$$
if $p+q=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I‘ve never seen that „technique“ used, but it is quite nice.... :)

Comment: Please be cautious about answering this type of question, @Ivan. Our policy is to try to only give hints so the OP can figure it out for themselves (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)).